# Error while fitting digamma function in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to fit digamma function to my data, but I am getting an
raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))
error 'TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([0.5    '} and there are lot of 0.5

Here is my data [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1It8Lqhfh7hgK_wOmThIHIeoMqqrb3zfB)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, loadtxt, pi, sqrt, sinh, log
from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit
from mpmath import digamma
import math
k = 1.38e-23
hcut = 1.0e-34
q = 1.6e-19
B = 7.15

data = loadtxt('Rxx-HLN.csv')
x = data[:, 2]
y1 = data[:, 3]
s = 1/y1
s0 = s[1]
y = s-s0


# define objective function: returns the array to be minimized
def fcn2min(params, x, y):
    """Model a decaying sine wave and subtract data."""
    Bs = params['Bs']
    Bp = params['Bp']
    Be = params['Be']
    model = (log(Bp/x)-digamma(0.5+(Bp/x)))+((log((Bs+Be)/x)-digamma(0.5+((Bs+Be)/x))))-((log((1.33*Bs+Bp)/x)-digamma(0.5+((1.33*Bs+Bp)/x))))
    return model - y


#    
params = Parameters()
params.add('Bs', value=9.1e-31)
params.add('Bp', value=1e-12)
params.add('Be', value=9.1e-31)



# do fit, here with the default leastsq algorithm
minner = Minimizer(fcn2min, params, fcn_args=(x, y))
result = minner.minimize()

# calculate final result
final = y + result.residual

# write error report
report_fit(result)

# try to plot results
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    plt.plot(x, final, 'r')
    plt.show()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I think that it has to do something with the mpf thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off using `scipy.special.digamma`. The `mpmath` module does arbitrary precision calculations, but the rest of the calculations in your code and in `lmfit` use numpy/scipy (or go down to C/Fortran code) that all used double-precision calculations.  That is, the fitting algorithm really will not give results better than double precision.

Also (and possibly related to your choice of `mpmath` in the first place):  The double-precision fitting algorithms in `scipy` and `lmfit` will not do a very good job with parameter values that span many orders of magnitude.  That is, you may need to recast your problem so that the parameter values are expected to be in the range of say 1.e-7 to 1.e+7 and put in scaling factors like your `q` and `hcut`. It seems like are doing this some, but you may need to be vigilant about this.